# nhibernate 3.3 one-to-many mapping-by-code updates children instead of inserting

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have this one-to-many association I created zilions of times with 'old' nhibernate or fluent. But I cann't make it work with mapping-by-code

These are the classes

```
 public class Parent
 {
      public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
 }

 public class Child
 {
      public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
 }
```

Nothing odd

and these are mappings classes

For Parent:

```
 Bag(x => x.Parent, m => m.Key(k => k.Column("Parent_id")));
```

Child:

```
 ManyToOne(x => x.Children, map => { map.Column("Parent_id"); map.Cascade(Cascade.All); });
```

If I do the following

```
 var parent = new Parent();
 parent.Children.Add(new Child());

 session.SaveOrUpdate(parent);
```

I got correct INSERT for parent, but it does an UPDATE for any child added

```
UPDATE TableChildren
......
WHERE Id = 0 <-????
```

What's am I missing? I'm banging my head!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see two issues. The mapping seems to be inverted (`Bag` should go for `Children`, `ManyToOne` for a `Parent`). The essential setting here is also the `inverse="true"`.

As in detail documented here:

- [Mapping-by-Code - Set and Bag](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-set-and-bag.html), we should add this:
- [Mapping-by-Code - ManyToOne](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-manytoone.html)

The Children should be mapped like this:

```
Bag(x => x.Children, map => {
    map.Inverse(true);
    map.Cascade(Cascade.All);
    map.Key(k => k.Column("Parent_id"));
});
```

And the Parent like this

```
ManyToOne(x => x.Parent, map => 
{ 
    map.Column("Parent_id"); 
});
```

The `inverse="true"` is a way how to instruct NHibernate, that each child can manage itself. So, once the child is added into the `Children` collection, we also have to set its `Parent`! NHibernate will then INSERT the child with the correct reference in one step.

Comment: Thank you. For the first it was a typo, I'm going to update the question. For the latter, you were right, but I wander I never used inverse this way before (and I use NHibernate since several years). I thought I had to use if I want to tell NH I manually manage children objects. I wander how old programs manage to work, indeed :D. I'm going to investigate.

Comment: Enjoy NHibernate, amazing tool really ;)

Comment: Yes it is! No comparison with other ORMs ;)